# Cell border with a varying range

Tags: vba, excel, formatting

I am trying to put a border around individual cells as I move through a FOR LOOP where the number of loops is determined by how many columns have content in them and the number of columns will vary between sheets.

It appears that I can't individually put a border around a dynamic cell location, rather I have to specify a range or a particular cell.  Is that correct?

Here is my code that I'm using to accomplish my goal...

```
Sub Sheet_Formatting()

   For Col_Count = 1 To Col_Count_Active_Sheet

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Active_Sheet).Cells(1, Col_Count).Interior.Color = RGB(100, 100, 100)   ' sets to the color ???
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Active_Sheet).Cells(1, Col_Count).Borders.LineStyle.xlContinuous        ' sets to the linestyle
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Active_Sheet).Cells(1, Col_Count).Borders.Weight.xlThick                ' sets to the border thickness
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Active_Sheet).Cells(1, Col_Count).Font.Bold = True                      ' sets to the text format to bold

   Next Col_Count
End Sub
```

I believe there is a way to accomplish the border specification but I can't use "Cells" to specify any borders.  The interior color and font work as desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between the [Range.Borders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822605.aspx) property and the [Border Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838428.aspx). Do not confuse the two.

```
Sub Sheet_Formatting()

   For Col_Count = 1 To Col_Count_Active_Sheet

        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Active_Sheet).Cells(1, col_Count)
            .Interior.Color = RGB(100, 100, 100)   ' sets to the color ???
            .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous      ' sets to the linestyle
            .Borders.Weight = xlThick              ' sets to the border thickness
            .Font.Bold = True                      ' sets to the text format to bold
        End With

   Next Col_Count

End Sub
```

I've cleaned up a few of the repetitious [.Parent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224980.aspx) references with a [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx). Not only does this make for cleaner code but it runs faster as well.

Answer (score 2):

You need assign the property values for Border , just like you did it for `Color` and `Bold`

```
Sub Sheet_Formatting()



   For Col_Count = 1 To Col_Count_Active_Sheet

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Active_Sheet).Cells(1, Col_Count).Interior.Color = RGB(100, 100, 100)   ' sets to the color ???
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Active_Sheet).Cells(1, Col_Count).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous       ' sets to the linestyle
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Active_Sheet).Cells(1, Col_Count).Borders.Weight = xlThick               ' sets to the border thickness
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Active_Sheet).Cells(1, Col_Count).Font.Bold = True                      ' sets to the text format to bold

   Next Col_Count
End Sub
```

Also, another way is :

`ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Active_Sheet).Cells(1, Col_Count).BorderAround (xlThin)`

Comment: what do you mean by add property values for border?  I thought that was what the xlContinuous and xlThick were for?

Comment: You are using this `.Borders.LineStyle.xlContinuous ` . Its not an assignment.  This is assignment `.Borders.LineStyle=xlContinuous ` Also, when your query is resolved, always mark it answered / upvote.